# Elixir with Plug and Cowboy: Disable nice error messages

Tags: heroku, elixir, production, cowboy, plug

I am using [heroku-buildpack-elixir](https://github.com/HashNuke/heroku-buildpack-elixir) to deploy an application to Heroku. My application consists of a simple Plug/Cowboy setup. I noticed that when unhandled exceptions occur, a nice error message appears, showing the stack trace and the lines of code where the error appeared.

This is ok for development environments, however on production environments I do not want my code to be visible to visitors. How can I disable or override the default behaviour?

I tried setting the `MIX_ENV` environment variable to `prod` in Heroku with no effect.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ changing `MIX_ENV` in production does not make much sense since there is even no `mix` application in the first place (unless you have explicitly included it in your release, which is basically wrong in a nutshell.)

Comment: @mudasobwa but it seems that `Mix.env` has the correct value though (look at the accepted answer). Where does it get the value from?

Comment: In the correct answer, this code is _compiled_. During the compilation stage `mix` is surely there and `Mix.env` is defined. In production, there is no trail of `mix` anymore. That said, in runtime there is _no conditional_ at all, this piece of code is compiled to void AST.

Comment: @mudasobwa the application is compiled on Heroku, that's why I thought the environment variables would also have effects at the compilation stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap the Plug.Debugger statement in an if clause. Running in prod environment no longer show errors as html pages. [source](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Debugger.html)

```
  if Mix.env == :dev do
    use Plug.Debugger, otp_app: :my_app
  end
```

Comment: are you using Plug.Debugger ? hard to find the solution without code....

Comment: Thanks - wrapping `use Plug.Debugger` in an if clause like in the example on https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Debugger.html does exactly what I need.
Could you add this to your answer for future readers?